# Upload File Make Public Get Download Link

Tags: java, upload, google-drive-api, share

I am stuck setting the reading permissions on a file that I uploaded successfully to Google Drive.

Moreover I would like to get the URL link to share it publicly.

I don't know why I shouldn't have access to change the permissions.

```
An error occurred: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file"
}
```

My code so far:

```
public class FilesUploader {


public static void uploadNow(Drive service) {

   //...
   String fileId = insertFile(service, f.getName(),  f.getName());

   if (fileId != null) {

      List<Permission> permissionList = retrievePermissions(service, fileId);
      for (Permission p : permissionList) {
        printPermission(service, fileId, p.getId());
        updatePermission(service, fileId, p.getId(), "reader");
        }
      }
    } 

}

/**
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update
 */
private static Permission updatePermission(Drive service, String fileId,
                                           String permissionId, String newRole) {
    try {
        // First retrieve the permission from the API.
        Permission permission = service.permissions().get(
                fileId, permissionId).execute();
        permission.setRole(newRole);
        return service.permissions().update(
                fileId, permissionId, permission).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert
 */
private static String insertFile(Drive service, String title, String filename) {
    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);


    // File's content.
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("", fileContent);
    try {
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();


        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        return file.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/get
 */
private static void printPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
                                    String permissionId) {
    try {
        Permission permission = service.permissions().get(
                fileId, permissionId).execute();


        System.out.println("Name: " + permission.getName());
        System.out.println("Role: " + permission.getRole());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
    }
}

/**
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list
 */
private static List<Permission> retrievePermissions(Drive service,
                                                    String fileId) {
    try {
        PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();
        return permissions.getItems();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution

```
insertPermission(service, fileId, "anyone", "reader");
System.out.println(  file.getWebContentLink());

private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
                                               String type, String role) {
        Permission newPermission = new Permission();

//        newPermission.setValue(value);
        newPermission.setType(type);
        newPermission.setRole(role);
        try {
            return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```